# isinstance и self.__class__ в классах в питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, классы

Объясните, пожалуйста, что такое `self.__class__`? То есть, например, когда используют функцию isinstance(), в скобках пишут объект и класс, имея ввиду проверку того, принадлежит ли этот объект этому классу. Но вот если есть такой класс:

```
class Rope:
    def __init__(self, length):
        self._length = length

    def __len__(self):
        # Переопределяем оператор len
        return self._length

    def __add__(self, other):
        # Переопределяем оператор +
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            # Если второй объект (то с чем складываем) того же класса
            return Rope(self._length + other._length)  # возвращаем новый объект
        elif isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            # Если второй объект - число
            return Rope(self._length + other)  # возвращаем новый объект
        else:
            raise TypeError
```

почему у первого isinstance в скобках пишут `self.__class__`? Что это вообще значит? Мы же хотим проверить принадлежит ли объект other тому же классу, что и self. Но ведь self принадлежит классу Rope. Почему бы тогда не написать так: isinstance(other, Rope)? Тем более, что, если написать просто Rope, то и смотрится попроще. В чем отличие (other, `self.__class__`) от (other, Rope), если self принадлежит классу Rope? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно `isinstance(other, self.__class__)` имеет смысл писать, если мы ожидаем, что от класса будут наследоваться другие классы, и мы хотим, чтобы тип сравнивался именно с типами тех дочерних классов, а не родительского `Rope`.

Но в данном коде в этом особого смысла нет, т.к. дальше идёт `return Rope`, то есть в дочернем классе этот метод наследовать без изменения не получится.

То есть для чего так написано в данном коде - надо спрашивать у автора этого кода, конкретно здесь это бессмыслено.

Если бы предполагалось, что от этого класса будут наследоваться другие, то ретурн надо было бы писать так: `return self.__class__(self._length + other._length)`

Comment: стоп. а что вы имеете ввиду под "в дочернем классе этот метод наследовать без изменения не получится"? в чем смысл наследователь родительский класс, если мы не будем его как то менять? ну то есть в дочернем же классе мы в любом случае как то модифицируем родительский класс. родительский класс исользуется просто как база, а дальше дочерний класс уже развивается сам. разве нет?

Comment: Ну, в дочернем классе же меняться будет не абсолютно всё. Данный конкретный метод может как переиспользоваться без изменения, так и может быть переопределён. И вот если бы там вообще всюду вместо явного Rope использовалось бы self.__class__, то я бы не колеблясь сказал, что автор предполагал его переиспользовать в потомках без переопределения. Но в текущем половинчатом виде его нельзя как есть переиспользовать в потомках, так как он будет возвращать экземпляр Rope, а не экземпляр класса потомка. Но если в потомках он переиспользоваться как есть не будет, то не понятно, зачем там self.__class__

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1223581/Помогите-пожалуйста-с-объяснением-сути-self-class-в-питоне.  Просто я не понял, как тут вставлять блочный код