# Помогите, пожалуйста, с объяснением сути self.__class__ в питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, классы

Вот у меня есть такой код:

```python
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, length, width):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
    def info(self):
        print('information')
class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, length, width):
        super().__init__(length, width)
    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self.__class__(self._length + other._length)
        else:
            print('damn')
```

какой именно класс проверяется в строке : `if isinstance(other, self.__class__)`? Это имеется ввиду класс Vehicle или класс Car? И как это вообще понять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот так допилил ваш код чтобы работал:

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, length, width):
        self._length = length
        self._width = width


    def info(self):
        print(self._length, self._width)


class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, length, width):
        super().__init__(length, width)

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self.__class__(self._length + other._length, self._width + other._width)
        else:
            print('damn')
```

> какой именно класс проверяется в строке : if isinstance(other,
> self.**class**)? Это имеется ввиду класс Vehicle или класс Car? И как
> это вообще понять?

можно сделать print и посмотреть что именно выводится

проверяется именно с `Car`

опять же легко проверить:

```
data1 = Car(10, 20)
data2 = Vehicle(30, 40)

data1 += data2
```

получим `damn`

Вообще более корректно написать код так:

если невозможно из-за неправильного типа данных сделать сложение - выбрасываем исключение и вне класса его обрабатываем

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, length, width):
        self._length = length
        self._width = width

    def info(self):
        print(self._length, self._width)


class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, length, width):
        super().__init__(length, width)

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, type(self).__bases__):
            return self.__class__(self._length + other._length, self._width + other._width)
        else:
            raise TypeError


data1 = Car(10, 20)
data2 = Vehicle(30, 40)

try:
    data1 += data2
    data1.info()
except:
   print("damn 1")

try:
    data1 += 3
    data1.info()
except:
   print("damn 2")
```

Но если стоит задача складывать в любом случае, только при некорректных входных данных не реагировать, то можно сделать и так:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, type(self).__bases__):
        return self.__class__(self._length + other._length, self._width + other._width)
    else:
        print('damn')
        return self
```

т.е. никакого сложения не произойдет, а вернется исходный класс и выдастся ваш текст

есть один недостаток - для `data1 += 3` все понятно - мы меняем существующий объект, но для  `data = data1 + 3` результат будет несколько нелогичным - `data = data1`

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117691/discussion-on-answer-by-zhihar------self-c).